# unsettled transactions to settled transaction in authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I have successfully charge the `customer payment profile`. These transactions can be viewed in the unsettled transaction. I want to ask why these not settled automatically.

Because when a user pay the value through his credit card. I want to show that the amount has been deducted and the client has received the payment. Or i have to suppose that `unsettled transaction` is also a successful case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsettled transactions are successful transactions. Unsettled just means the transactions have not been sent to the bank for settlement which is what starts the process of capturing those funds. This is to allow you the opportunity to void those transactions if necessary.

Settlement happens nightly so those transactions will show as settled within 24 hours of being processed.

Comment: thank you for your reply. What if the customer did not have enough money in card or in the bank account? this goes into unsettled or the auth.net itself give me the error about not having the enough money?

Comment: If the card does not have the credit available to it at the time of the transaction it will be declined by the bank. It won't be approved and never reach the unsettled or settled state.

Comment: okay okay actually i am in sandbox environment and every transaction is going successfully without the error in the live/production it will be declined?

Comment: Correct. In the live environment those transactions will be declined. The sandbox just approves everything to make testing easier. You can [simulate declines and errors if you need to](https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide/).

Comment: Hi John. I know this is an old answer. The question is: unsettled eCheck transactions are the same way? Should I assume an unsettled transaction as positive at the time it was placed, even if it settles days later?